# SwiftUI Crash BoxVTable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am seeing an odd crash with some beta testers on TestFlight. It seems to be at app startup, but prior to the point where we are making any network calls. There does not seem to be a lot on the internet regarding this, and symbolication isn't helping much either. Just curious if anyone has run into this before and what they did about it? I have had it happen on two tester's devices and I have never been able to recreate the issue locally.

For a bit of context, I am creating a list view on my main screen with a `LazyVGrid` that contains a `LazyHGrid` inside of it that are both filled using published vars from my viewmodel, though this seems to happen prior to any of those being created.

Thanks for any ideas / help

[image: crash symbolication]

Edit: Some more details / actual code:

The view with the grids:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct FeaturedView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @EnvironmentObject var tabRouter : TabRouter
    @StateObject var loadingViewModel = LoadingViewModel()
    private let imageProcessor = SVGImgProcessor()
    private let playerManager = PlayerManager.shared
    private var gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.flexible())]
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        let paddingHStack: CGFloat = 25
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                Color(hex:"#00091C").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Hello, \(loadingViewModel.name)")
                                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .font(Font.custom("poppins-medium", size: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(hex:"#667C95"))
                                .padding(.leading, 15)
                                .padding(.top, 15)
                                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                            Image("PremiumStar")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
                                .opacity(userDefaults.isSubscriber() ? 1 : 0)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Settings Clicked")
                            viewRouter.currentPage = .settingsFlow
                        }) {
                            Image("Settings")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 22.0, height: 22.0)
                                .padding(15)
                        }
                    }
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 17) {
                                ForEach(loadingViewModel.getCategories()) { category in
                                    Text(category.title)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(Font.custom("poppins-bold", size: 30))
                                    ZStack {
                                        KFImage(URL(string: (category.background?.svg!)!))
                                            .resizable()
                                            .setProcessor(imageProcessor)
                                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - padding, height: 175, alignment: .topLeading)
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                            .clipped()
                                            .cornerRadius(5)
                                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                            LazyHGrid(rows: gridItemLayout, spacing: 20){
                                                ForEach(loadingViewModel.getSoundsForCategory(category: category.key)) { sound in
                                                    Button(action: {
                                                        playerManager.play(sound: sound)
                                                    }) {
                                                        VStack {
                                                            ZStack{
                                                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                                                    .opacity(0.85)
                                                                ZStack(alignment:.bottomTrailing){
                                                                    KFImage(URL(string: sound.icon.png!)!)
                                                                        .resizable()
                                                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                                        .clipped()
                                                                    Image("LockIcon")
                                                                        .frame(width: 12, height: 12, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                                                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                                        .clipped()
                                                                        .hidden(loadingViewModel.isSubscriber || sound.tier != 2)
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            Text(sound.name)
                                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                                .font(Font.custom("poppins-regular", size: 12))
                                                                .lineLimit(1)
                                                                .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 90, maxWidth: 100, alignment: .center)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }.padding(.horizontal)
                                        }
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - paddingHStack, height: 175, alignment: .topLeading)
                                    }
                                    Button("Explore All"){
                                        print("Explore All \(category.title) Tapped")
                                        tabRouter.categoryKey = category.key
                                        tabRouter.hasChanged = true
                                        tabRouter.currentTab = 1
                                    }
                                    .font(Font.custom("poppins-bold", size: 15))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                }
                            }.padding(.bottom, 120)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FeaturedView()
    }
}
```

That is loaded by this tab view, which goes between two screens which share the same viewModel / load the same data

```swift
    // MARK: Tab View
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
                FeaturedView()
                    .environmentObject(tabRouter)
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("FEATURED", image: "Featured")
                    }.tag(0)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            if (showOverlay && !isExpanded){
                                playView
                            } else {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                SoundView()
                    .environmentObject(tabRouter)
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("SOUNDS", image: "Sounds")
                    }.tag(1)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            if (showOverlay && !isExpanded){
                                playView
                            } else {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                    )
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example of your issue. Otherwise it'll be hard to give specific help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @JanBrinker - added the code

Comment: Hi @brettywhite, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in my app. Did you find out more about this?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing yet. It seems to occur randomly on very few devices and I've had no luck pinpointing it.